# Finding the minimum element position of a cudaMalloc'ed array by thrust::min_element

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to find the smallest element in a certain CUDA array

```
float *p;
...    
thrust::device_ptr<float> pWrapper(p);    
thrust::device_ptr<float> pos = 
               thrust::min_element(pWrapper, pWrapper + MAXX * MAXY, thrust::minimum<float>());
```

`p` is linear device memory, and `pWrapper` is a `thrust::device_ptr`.

When I use `device_vector`, it is easy to find the location of the smallest element by

```
min_element(someDeviceVector) - someDeviceVector.begin()
```

Opposite to that, when the type supplied to the `min_element` call is a `device_ptr`, the return type of the `min_element` is `float *p` (according to the defined template of the `device_vector`). From the code snippet I just provided, I can't tell what is the location of the smallest value and how can I extract it from the array.

I tried to subtract from the return type of `min_element` the address of both `p` and `pWrapper` but neither worked.

Comment: Don't use ```thrust::minimum``` here.  You want ```thrust::less``` (or nothing, ```thrust::less``` is the default).

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that i simply need to use the * operator on the min_element out-coming result.

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you are considering the very common case when you have a `cudaMalloc`'ed array and you want to find the position and the value of its minimum element by `thrust::min_element`. Below, I'm providing a full example of that in the hope that it could be useful to other users.

Basically, the solution below shares the same idea of wrapping a `thrust::device_ptr` around the `cudaMalloc`'ed linear memory. However, the position is found by `thrust::distance`.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 16;

    srand(time(NULL));

    // --- Host side memory allocation and initialization
    float *h_A = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_A[i] = rand();

    // --- Device side memory allocation and initialization
    float *d_A; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, N * sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    thrust::device_ptr<float> dp = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_A);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> pos = thrust::min_element(dp, dp + N);

    unsigned int pos_index = thrust::distance(dp, pos);
    float min_val;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(&min_val, &d_A[pos_index], sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("d_A[%i] = %f\n", i, h_A[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Position of the minimum element = %i; Value of the minimum element = %f\n", thrust::distance(dp, pos), min_val);

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```